# Cache pages for anonymous users stuck on

Tags: caching

I can't turn off the "Cache pages for anonymous users " cache option.

I uncheck it and then hit save as usual but it stays on. Is there some sort of module conflict causing this or possibly an issue with the database?

[image: Thanks]

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes i did. lots of times

Comment: There might be issue of below module or other which would be having issue of cookie stored causing the issue for not caching the page. https://www.drupal.org/project/recently_read Recently read has performance issue stated above.

Comment: Did you check your console and your error logs?

Comment: Check settings.php for a config override on that variable

Comment: thanks clive that was it. I had some leftover varnish code inside the settings.php file. after commenting out all is ok

Comment: Commenting out or deleting unused memcache and Varnish code within my settings.php file solved the problem.